# Grails: Intercept the creation of a service from a plugin?

Tags: grails, plugins, service

I have a plugin that's shared between multiple applications and I need to set some application specific options that will be used in a service in the plugin.  It's an in house written plugin, however, the plugin has to be unaware of which application it's running in.

The best way I can think of doing this is to have some code run in the application right after the service is created in the plugin and call a method on the service to set the options.  Is this possible?

If it's not possible, what other design could I implement to pass options to the plugin from the application.

Btw, these options need to be set when the application starts as well as throughout the running of the application.

Comment: Why not just create the service bean in your Resources.groovy in the application then you can set properties on it all you want. Or even just call methods on it from Bootstrap.groovy when the application starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to use Bootstrap.groovy to to call a method(s) on a Grails service when an application starts. This service can be provided by the application or plugins in the application. Here is a quick example of how to do so:

### Bootstrap.groovy

```
class BootStrap {

   def myExampleService

   def init = { servletContext ->
      myExampleService.someMethodOnTheService()
   }
}
```